# FME Server is not able to connect to ESRI enterprise geodatabase and shows no error

Tags: arcgis-server, fme-form, fme-flow

I have an environment with a FME Server 2018.1.2 Build 18590 and ArcGIS Server 10.6.1.

It has been running 2 pretty similar workspaces with no problem (A and B).

The ArcGIS server was upgraded to 10.7.1. After that the following behavior is observed:

Workspace A Fails with this log:

```
 Creating reader for format: Esri Geodatabase (ArcSDE Geodb) 
 Trying to find a DYNAMIC plugin for reader named `GEODATABASE_SDE' 
 Loaded module 'GEODATABASE_SDE' from file 'C:\Program Files\FMEServer\Server\fme\GEODATABASE9.dll' 
 FME API version of module 'GEODATABASE_SDE' matches current internal version (3.8 20180604) 
 Performing query against GEODATABASE_SDE dataset `<Unused>' 
 Opening the Geodatabase reader
```

Here the log stops.

Then, Workspace B is triggered, and shows the following in the same part as the Workspace A

```
 Creating reader for format: Esri Geodatabase (ArcSDE Geodb) 
 Trying to find a DYNAMIC plugin for reader named `GEODATABASE_SDE' 
 Loaded module 'GEODATABASE_SDE' from file 'C:\Program Files\FMEServer\Server\fme\GEODATABASE9.dll' 
 FME API version of module 'GEODATABASE_SDE' matches current internal version (3.8 20180604) 
 Performing query against GEODATABASE_SDE dataset `<Unused>' 
 Opening the Geodatabase reader 
 FME has checked out an Esri license. The product checked out is 'ArcServer' 
 Installed ArcGIS version is '10.7' 
 Connection made to server 'MYSERVER' for dataset 'UPDM' (transactional version 'sde.DEFAULT') using instance 'sde:sqlserver:MYSERVER' and user ID 'myuser' 
 ArcSDE release: '10.0'. Underlying database: 'SQL Server' 
 R_3 Reader: Using Enhanced geometry ......
.....
```

Log continues and finish successfully.

Here is the tricky :

If Workspace A is triggered again, it works fine.

After several times (3-4) start failing again.

Then I run the Workspace B and the Workspace A works again.

I noticed that it breaks just prior to the activation of the license. always is in the same location (First Feature reader with format Esri Geodatabase ArcSDE Geodb).

I know that this [article](https://community.safe.com/s/article/notes-on-fme-and-esri-versions-and-compatibility) states that I should be using FME 2019.1 but the thing that caught my attention is the Workspace A works, and fail once in while. moreover the Workspace B does not fail.

Comment: can you put FME Server in DEBUG_LEVEL = SUPER_VERBOSE https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Server_Documentation/ReferenceManual/message_logger_properties.htm and see if it logs a better output (or contact safe software for support)

Comment: @Mapperz , I just did what you suggest, for the engines and for the core, then I restart the services of FME server. after that ran again the job, but the log looks the same